# mod_rewrite for specific url only

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm into rewriting a url in different ways. I mean I want to know how to use mod_rewrite so I can do the following:

1- convert a .php to html for a speific url
i.e: from `www.mydomain.com/news.php` to `www.mydomain.com/news.html`

I found some interesting codes, but not sure which one works without any errors...

some of what I found:

`RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\w+).html$ index.php?id=$1&title=$2`

2- convert any sub url of that news.php file to

> news.php?do=news&id=24455

so the topics or threads show like this without slashes /

I find the 2nd question a lot difficult, but sure there must be a solution for that.

any idea how to get both questions done for a specific url like what I stated above...!!

Thanks

Comment: for example, news.php is the main folder 'url' so anything comes after is sub url like --> news/article1.php or sometimes news.php?art2432... and so on... maybe I didn't put it in the right name, but sure everyone can get it :)

Comment: `news/article1.php` or `news/article1.html`? Which one do you want to be visible in the user's browser address bar? "and so on" --- it doesn't work like that. You need to define an **exact** template for the urls.

Comment: I guess you are right. I define the exact template. ok, how about if threads are added to news.php ---> can't that be like this **news.php?do=news&id=24455**

Comment: and what is the original url that should be rewritten to it? `/news/24455.html`?

Comment: yes, exactly. /news/24455.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> convert a .php to html for a speific url i.e: from www.mydomain.com/news.php to www.mydomain.com/news.html

```
RewriteRule ^news\.html$ /news.php
```

Guess for the second (assuming you want to rewrite `/news/foo.html` urls):

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)\.html$ /news.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Great the code above did the work for rewriting the .php to .html, Thanks a lot. The only thing now is playing with .html as I'm trying now.

Comment: by the way, previously with .php url, I get `news.php?c=111 `originally when I add any thread...

Comment: @Digital site: I have no idea what you're talking about :-S

Comment: it is ok, I think your solution will do. Thanks a lot, mate